# VUe-storefront Paypal express checkout token issue

Tags: magento2, vue-storefront

I have enable paypal express checkout in magento 2 and add api detail. paypal works in magento 2. Then I have installed paypal extension in vue storefront from below link:

https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/integrations/paypal-payments.html#the-architecture

Then I tried to place order and paypal dialogue box is also open. but when I click pay now button it throws error for me.

Error: PayPal NVP gateway errors: Express Checkout token was issued for a merchant account other than yours (#10409: You're not authorized to access this info)

Anyone know about this issue